# Joining a pandas table with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables that I want to join - the main table has index `SourceID`, the sub-table is multi-indexed as it comes from a pivot table - indexes are `(SourceID, sourceid)`

**How can I join a table with a single index to one with multi-index (or change the multi-indexed table to singular)?**

The sub-table is created as follows:

```py
d = {'SourceID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'Year': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3], 'Sales': [100, 200, 300, 400 , 500, 600, 700], 'Profit': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_sub = (
  df
  .pivot_table(
    index=['SourceID'],
    columns=['Year'],
    values=['Sales', 'Profit'],
    fill_value=0,
    aggfunc='mean'
  )
  # .add_prefix('sales_')
  .reset_index()
)

L = [(a, f'{a.lower()}{b}') for a, b in df_sub.columns]
df_sub.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L)
df_sub = df_sub.reset_index()
```

I'm then trying to join it with the main table `df_main`

```py
df_all = df_sub.join(df_main.set_index('SourceID'), on='SourceID.sourceid')
```

but this fails due to the multi-index. The index in the sub-table could be single as long as I don't lost the multi-index on the other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but then MultiIndex values are converted to tuples:

```
df_all = df_sub.join(df.set_index('SourceID'), on=[('SourceID','sourceid')])
print (df_all)
```

If want `MultiIndex` in output is necessary convert `df` columns to `MultiIndex` too, e.g. by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['orig'], df1.columns])

df_all = df_sub.join(df1.set_index([('orig','SourceID')]), on=[('SourceID','sourceid')])
```